# When would you see Jquery dollar sign used at the end of the name of something

Tags: jquery

When would you see the jQuery dollar sign used at the end of the name of something such as `plot$` or `plot$.getName()`?

What does it mean when the dollar sign is at the end of a name like that?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing, in and of itself. The `$` is just another legal character in identifiers, nothing more, nothing less.

It may be that whatever codebase you're using assigns some special convention to using a `$` at the end of the name, but it's nothing standardized. jQuery (and some other libraries) just used `$` (on its own) because it was convenient, short, and (at the time) relatively unlikely to be used for anything else.

You sometimes see the `$` used at the beginning of names in code that uses jQuery, to indicate that the variable points to a jQuery instance. It could be the code is doing that. But as `getName` isn't a jQuery function, probably not. :-) (Unless `getName` is provided by a plug-in.)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't mean anything special. `$` is a valid character to be used in the variable name.

So `plot$` doesn't have any special meaning in comparison to, for example, `plotA`